# SQL Group by Max not desired results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I'm using SQL Server 2014 and have a table like this:

```
PK    ContactID  Tele    Mob   Land  Email  Txt
1       10        1       0     1     1      1
2       10        0       1     0     0      1
3       12        1       3     1     1      1
```

The desired result is:

```
PK    ContactID  Tele    Mob   Land  Email  Txt
2       10        0       1     0     0      1
3       12        1       3     1     1      1
```

However, if  I perform a GroupBy \ Max:

```
SELECT        MAX(PK) AS PK, ContactID, Tele, Mob, Land, Email, Txt
FROM            Contacts
GROUP BY ContactID, Tele, Mob, Land, Email, Txt
```

I'm just receiving:

```
PK    ContactID  Tele    Mob   Land  Email  Txt
1       10        1       0     1     1      1
2       10        0       1     0     0      1
3       12        1       3     1     1      1
```

How do I modify to give me the desired results?

Comment: You need to max the other fields anf group by your PK and/or contact id

Comment: What is the reasoning behind your desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function to make it.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ContactID ORDER BY PK DESC) rn
    FROM Contacts
) t1
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The last by PK row for a ContactId using `top with ties`

```
SELECT top(1) with ties *
FROM Contacts
ORDER BY row_number() over(partition by ContactID order by PK desc)
```